# Copy slice into its own array

Tags: arrays, rust, slice, memcpy, borrow-checker

I want to copy the values at one slice of an array into another slice.

The obvious way (using iteration) is:

```
for i in 0..10 {
    self.ram[i] = self.ram[20 + i];
}
```

However, that seems rather inefficient.

The usual way to copy a slice:

```
arr[0..10].copy_from_slice(&arr[20..30]);
```

does not work as `arr` is borrowed twice.

The only other way to do this that comes to mind is `std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping`, which is unsafe.

What is the best way to copy a slice into its own array (while knowing that source and destination do not overlap)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`copy_within()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_within):

```rust
arr.copy_within(20..30, 0);
```

Note that it does not require them to not overlap.

If you're sure they do not overlap, and you want to exploit that, you can use unsafe code:

```rust
let p = arr.as_mut_ptr();
unsafe {
    std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(p.add(20), p, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Are there any advantages in using the unsafe version? The code must be pretty fast so any kind of efficiency-boost would be desirable.

Comment: @NikitaDemodov Yes, two of them: no bounds checks (not relevant unless you invoke the function a lot of times - those bounds checks are once per _copy_, not once per _element_) and `memcpy()` instead of `memmove()` which may be a little faster, depending on a lot of things. The manual version is the worse - LLVM is unable to optimize it even to `memmove()` even with `get_unchecked()` (no bounds checks), and I think even does not vectorize it. You can compare the assembly [here](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/6bdr693oo).

Comment: @NikitaDemodov I'm pretty sure it is possible to let LLVM eliminate the bound checks even with the `copy_within()` version, but that will require unsafe code (so almost no advantage) + my (few) attempts have failed.

Comment: Thank you very much! (I didn't know Godbolt supported Rust!) I must say I am quite surprised that the manual version isn't even optimized to only perform the bounds check once, but instead checks it on every iteration.

Comment: @NikitaDemodov This is impossible since the panic message includes the index, and so doing that would change observable behavior. There are issues to improve the situation, though, but generally re-slicing at the beginning of the function is enough.

Comment: But the panicking index is just `slice.len()`, which should stay constant in Rust. I thought this was exactly the kind of optimization Rust's borrow checker was supposed to make possible.

Comment: @NikitaDemodov Yes, in this case, but LLVM is not smart enough to realize that (and I don't understand how this is related to the borrow checker).

Comment: @Chayin Friedman My thought process was that a different thread shouldn't be able to have a (safe) mutable reference to the array and change its length midway through the loop, but I realize that this is quite a weird thought to have.. :)

Comment: @NikitaDemodov This is a data race, and it will be undefined behavior in other languages (C/C++), so LLVM can safely assume that. Rustc prevents that statically (although not solely based on the borrow checker), but it does not open the door to new optimization opportunities.